# Is there any community available for iOS developers in Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

One of my friends is coming from iOS environment, and he is searching a lot for iOS community in Stack Exchange, just like [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) community, but he did not find.

Is there any community available for him?

Comment: You mean "[apple.se]"?

Comment: @PangThanks a lot .......

Comment: [android.se] is _not_ for Android developers, but rather for Android users.

Comment: @PatrickHofman..Actually Sir, I want to make a positive image in SO/SE and i really appreciate your answer but due to that downvotes, I made a decision to delete that question... Sorry Sir!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For developers, I would say [Stack Overflow](//stackoverflow.com) is the place. There is a large [ios tag](//stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) there.

For questions related to the use of iOS and it's devices, [Ask Different](//apple.stackexchange.com/) is the place to go.